# VBA to copy width of the columns

Tags: excel, vba

The VBA code below copies the data from a source data sheet and pastes it onto a specific sheet. However, I need it to also paste the width of the columns on the source data sheet. Would that be possible? thanks for any help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim tableName As String
Dim tableRange As Range
Dim TypeOfCosts As String
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Range("X1").Text = "aaaa" Then
    TypeOfCosts = "_bbbb"
ElseIf Range("L3") = "cccc" Then
    TypeOfCosts = "_dddd"
Else
    TypeOfCosts = ""
End If

tableName = Range("Y1").Text & TypeOfCosts & "_Costs"

On Error Resume Next
Set tableRange = Application.Range(tableName)
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Names.Count
    If Not (tableRange Is Nothing) And Err = 0 Then
    Range("K9").Resize(10000, 10000).ClearContents
    Range("K9").Resize(10000, 10000).ClearFormats
    tableRange.Copy Destination:=Range("M8")
Else
    Err.Clear
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at the .PasteSpecial method. (espacially the .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidth method).

Comment: or .ColumnWidth property

Comment: After the tableRange.Copy line. I'm on mobile so I can't test but you should try tableRange.Copy   and then tableRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll and also tableRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your code is executing as desired then instead of

```
tableRange.Copy Destination:=Range("M8")
```

you may write

```
tableRange.Copy    
With Range("M8")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

tableRange.Copy Destination:=Range("M8") is best practive, it will skip the clipboard that can mess up stuff. So you should keep the approach. I will rather use an interator for copyrange column widths and set them if they are different.
See below an extract from my library that clones a sheet data and shapes to another without actually breaking references (using clear) and without using the copy buffer that might fail in large sheets.

```
' clear all Shapes
For Each varShape In shtNewSheet.Shapes
    'console varShape.Name
    varShape.Delete
Next

' clear all Cells
With shtNewSheet.UsedRange
    ' first clear data from current sheet
    .Clear
    ' copy new data and shapes
    shtPrevSheet.UsedRange.Copy shtNewSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1)
    ' as with all things excel, going bakwards actually works
    ' set columns widths
    For i = .Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        If .Columns(i).ColumnWidth <> shtPrevSheet.Columns(i).ColumnWidth Then
            .Columns(i).ColumnWidth = shtPrevSheet.Columns(i).ColumnWidth
        End If
    Next
    ' optional set rows heights
    For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If .Rows(i).RowHeight <> shtPrevSheet.Rows(i).RowHeight Then
            .Rows(i).RowHeight = shtPrevSheet.Rows(i).RowHeight
        End If
    Next
    
    ' this to reset the selection and move to top page, kind of not really necessary
    shtPrevSheet.Cells(1, 1).Copy shtNewSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    
End With
```