# How to paste all including shapes and column widths in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to paste a row onto each new sheet. I am trying to get it to paste all, including shapes and column widths. `ActiveSheet.Paste` includes Shapes but not Column Widths. I have tried `Sh.Range("1:1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` but this pastes neither the shapes or column widths.

I know I need to incorporate `xlPasteColumnwidths` but sure how to do this with `ActiveSheet.Paste`.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Sheets("Template").Range("1:1").Copy
    Sh.Range("1:1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814565/vba-to-copy-width-of-the-columns

Comment: Thanks @KinSiang. This works for column widths but doesnt inlcude shapes like ```ActiveSheet.Paste``` does. Also what is the meaning of ```False, False``` after PasteSpecial?

Comment: You can check MSN link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial, it has explained the meaning. Or probably you can show the image what are you trying to do.

Comment: @KinSiang In regards to shapes I mean, as an example a rectangle or button with a macro assigned. This Shape is hovering over Row 1.  A manual copy/paste of Row 1 will copy/paste the Shapes. ActiveSheet.Paste also pastes the Shapes, just not column widths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet

Set wsInput = Sheets("Template")
Set wsOutput = Sheets("Whatever") '<~~ Change as applicable

wsInput.Rows(1).Copy wsOutput.Rows(1)

wsInput.Rows(1).Copy
wsOutput.Rows(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, _
                                     Operation:=xlNone, _
                                     SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                     Transpose:=False
```

> I am trying to make it work on creation of a new sheet. My knowledge of vba is zero so I'm sure it is not the correct way, however I have managed to get it work. I will add it as an answer. Please comment if there is a better way! – aye cee 2 mins ago

If you want to perform the copy paste when a new sheet is added then you need to make slight amends to the above code as shown below.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    
    Set wsInput = Sheets("Template")
    
    wsInput.Rows(1).Copy Sh.Rows(1)
    
    wsInput.Rows(1).Copy
    sh.Rows(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, _
                                         Operation:=xlNone, _
                                         SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                         Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to make it work on creation of a new sheet. My knowledge of vba is zero so I'm sure it is not the correct way, however I have managed to get it work. I will add it as an answer. Please comment if there is a better way!

Comment: The above code that I gave is tried and tested. If it is to be added when a new sheet is created then you need to make slight amends to the above code.  See the updated post. you may have to refresh the page to see it

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted Siddaharth's answer above and it works very well. Just thought I would post the solution I had come up with prior to that. I have very little vba knowledge, so this may be inefficient but here it is.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Sheets("Template").Range("1:1").Copy
    Sh.Range("1:1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sh.Range("1:1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths 
End Sub
```