# Why using (PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths) clears the previous pasted values when copy (non-contiguous) ranges?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to copy `non-contiguous` ranges from workbook (wb1) to another(wb2). 
**Problem**: using (PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths) **clears** the previous pasted values.
**Steps to Produce issue:** fill some cells and select a non-contiguous range with the same first and last rows e.g. `A2:B3` and `D2:E3`.
 Now when you run the sub, you will notice that the column widths are copied while the data that was copied via `srg.Copy drg` has **disappeared**.
 If you step through the code, you will see that the data was copied and right after (not before) executing the line `drg.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths` the data is gone.
on all vba codes I saw, I copy source values and if required copy format after it. 
**Sure**:I could fix that issue by copying columns width then values.

```
srg.Copy
drg.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
srg.Copy drg
```

But **I need to understand why this abnormal issue happens**. 
Grateful for any help.

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook    'Source Workbook
Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Selection
 
Dim wb2 As Workbook: Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add  'Destination Workbook
Dim drg As Range: Set drg = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
 
srg.Copy drg
srg.Copy
drg.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
```

Comment: This may solve the issue you are having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814565/vba-to-copy-width-of-the-columns  try using `with` and `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False`

Comment: Not answering your question, but you could also `drg.entirecolumn.columnwidth = srg.entirecolumn.columnwidth`.

Comment: Specific to your code, are you running exactly what is written, where you're copying the 'complete' data then trying to paste the widths later, or are you just putting in what you've tried?  I can only hope that you commented out the `srg.copy drg` before trying to `xlpastecolumnwidths`.

Comment: @Cyril ,I tried `drg.entirecolumn.columnwidth = srg.entirecolumn.columnwidth` and found that values on destination **wb1** not cleared , But also columnwidth not applied (applied only if `srg.Columns.Count = 1`)

Comment: I am afraid that this behavior of `xlPasteColumnWidths` can only be considered as a bug. It cannot have a logical explanation. Since Excel/VBA is able to deal with copying value, even for discontinuous ranges (of course, with data on the same rows and columns), it should deal similarly with column widths. Something in the Excel internal algorithm is wrong. It looks that VBA is able to eliminate the blank columns/rows, when paste the value, but it does not keep the value empty, in case of only column widths pasting. A null string is applied to each cell of the pasted range. Why? A buggy way...

Comment: @FaneDuru ,I guessed that from beginning of issue, but I was not sure.`If you wish, you can put your comment as an answer`.

Comment: No, this is not an answer. It is only an opinion. We cannot answer only based on our opinion...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After long search on internet, specifically with Microsoft own documentation about **xlPasteColumnWidths** [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype)

**I concluded the following:** 
this behavior of xlPasteColumnWidths can only be considered as a **bug**. It cannot have a logical explanation. Since Excel/VBA is able to deal with copying value, even for discontinuous ranges (of course, with data on the same rows and columns), it should deal similarly with column widths. Something in the Excel internal algorithm is wrong. It looks that VBA is able to eliminate the blank columns/rows, when paste the value, but it does not keep the value empty, in case of only column widths pasting. A null string is applied to each cell of the pasted range.

Comment: Well in my experience if you detect the bug yourself, and you understand the mechanics of it (as you state, the column widths may be preserved, but the data is not)... So usually it's easier to copy the data to 1 variable you define, then the column widths (even if they are "supposed" to contain data), set as another variable.  So then you end up with 2 copy / pastes to get what you wanted.  Yeah it's a bug, but would you rather fix it now yourself or wait for Microsoft with some unknown timeline?  I usually just find a workaround, post an issue, and move on...

Comment: @Matt ,I tried your suggestion, But the same issue still exists.It is definitely a bug with `xlPasteColumnWidths`

Comment: Did you try changing the order of what gets copied?  Since you know the data is gone after doing the pastecolumnwidths do a normal paste of the data first. Then do the columnwidth one.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this "bug" occurs in the Mac version of VBA for Excel as well.

I'm not sure if it is helpful in your instance, but the problem seems to be triggered solely by the pasteSpecial operation when copied from a discontiguous range. Because the column width must be the same for all cells in the column, you can get the desired behavior by copying only the first row of the discontiguous source when trying to set the column widths.  I've done this by adding ".Rows(1)" to the copy statement (second-to-last line) as you see here:

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook: Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook    'Source Workbook
Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Selection

Dim wb2 As Workbook: Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add  'Destination Workbook
Dim drg As Range: Set drg = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

srg.Copy drg
srg.Rows(1).Copy
drg.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
```

This does not explain why the "bug" exists but may be helpful in working around it.

As pointed out by Waleed in a comment below, the solution above does not adjust the column widths when the individual ranges that make up the discontiguous range are in different columns.  To do that, we need to iterate over each individual area in the discontiguous range.  Here's a version that does that:

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook: Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook    'Source Workbook
Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Selection

Dim wb2 As Workbook: Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add  'Destination Workbook
Dim drg As Range: Set drg = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

srg.Copy drg

Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To srg.Areas.Count
   srg.Areas(x).Copy
   drg.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
   If x = 1 Then
     ' if the ranges are in the same columns, we are done
     If srg.Areas(x).Cells(1).Column = srg.Areas(x + 1).Cells(1).Column Then Exit For
   End If
   ' adjust the destination range to receive the next pastespecial
   Set drg = drg.Offset(0, srg.Areas(x).Columns.Count)
Next
```

Comment: now it is obvious that this issue is a bug regardless of system type.I tried your modified code .It dose not clear the previous values ,But column widths are copied correctly `only` for the **first area of source range** `Areas(1)`. Upvoted

Comment: Good point Waleed:  I've updated this answer to handle column widths correctly when the component ranges of the discontiguous range are in different columns.